# PHP how to use data posted from Python script?

Tags: php, python, post

I have a python script that does pa POST request to my php page (json format). After posting I see from the response that the data is sent at PHP through `print(r.text)` in python script.

The problem is that I can't use the data from PHP side - I cannot print it or write to files etc.

What could I be doing wrong here?

Part of python script:

```
        data_json = {
            "measurementTime"   : first_line.split(',')[0],
            "windSpeed"         : first_line.split(',')[1],
            "windGust"          : first_line.split(',')[2],
            "windSpeedCount"    : first_line.split(',')[3],
            "rain"              : first_line.split(',')[12],
            "windDirection"     : first_line.split(',')[13],
            "inputVoltage"      : first_line.split(',')[14],
            "solarRadiation"    : first_line.split(',')[15],
            "temperature"       : first_line.split(',')[16],
            "windSpeed"         : first_line.split(',')[18],
            "humidity"          : first_line.split(',')[19],
            "barPressure"       : first_line.split(',')[20]
        }

        url = 'http://localhost/index.php'

        r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data_json))

        print(r.text)   # here I can see that data has been sent
        print(r.status_code)
```

PHP (index.php):

```
    <?php
        $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
        print_r($json);
    ?>
```

Python script output:

```
    ...
    <body>

        {"measurementTime": "2018-01-25 17:52:25", "windSpeed": "9.0", "windGust": "0.0", "windSpeedCount": "0", "rain": "1.50", "windDirection": "0", "inputVoltage": "13.51", "solarRadiation": "", "temperature": "0.00", "humidity": "87.5", "barPressure": "1004.473"}

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does `r.status_code` print? 200?

Comment: Yes, it's 200. And I can see the json received in the response but I cannot print it or use otherwise

Comment: how were you able to see if it is not getting printed?/

Comment: I just refreshed the page and the `print_r($json)` did not print anything.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that I can't use the data from PHP side - I cannot
>   print it or write to files etc

Here is a php script that will write the python json to a file:

```
<?php

file_put_contents(
    "../tmp/data.txt", 
    file_get_contents('php://input') . "\n"
);

echo "Got it";

?>
```

The only problem I had was with permissions to write the file. I'm using apache2, so I created a `tmp` directory under the apache2 directory, and I gave all users the ability to write to the directory:

```
/usr/local/apache2/$ mkdir tmp
/usr/local/apache2/$ ls -al
...
...
drwxr-xr-x    2 7stud  admin    64 Jan 25 13:23 tmp

/usr/local/apache2$ chmod a+w tmp     #all+write, where all=user,group,other
/usr/local/apache2$ ls -al
...
...
drwxrwxrwx    2 7stud  admin    64 Jan 25 13:23 tmp
```

After running the following python script:

```
import requests
import json

data_json = {
    "measurementTime"   : 10,
    "windSpeed"         : 20
}

url = 'http://localhost:8080/php1.php'
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data_json))

print(r.text)   
print(r.status_code)
```

in the python window, I see:

> Got it
>   200

and in the apache2 window I can see that the json was written to the file:

```
/usr/local/apache2$ cat tmp/data.txt
{"measurementTime": 10, "windSpeed": 20}
```

Here's a php script that uses the json data:

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);

$sum = $obj->measurementTime + $obj->windSpeed;
echo "The sum was: $sum";

?>
```

In the python window, I see:

> The sum was: 30
>   200

Comment: Yes, that is what I had done already - I am able to see and operate with the data and see it in the python script. But I am not able to save the data e.g. place the json objects into an array or print them out on the index.php page

Comment: @ApeDinky, Placing the json objects into an array does not *save the data*, but to get the data into an array, instead of object as in my example, you would write: `$arr = json_decode($json, true);`.   And your python script, shows that you did indeed *print them out on the index.php page*. What do you think that stuff is between the `<body>` tag?